# Default Firewall Rules on Windows 2008 Standard And Enterprise Edition Different?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ping, windows-firewall

Are the default firewall rules for Windows 2008 Standard Edition and Enterprise Edition the same or are they slightly different?

Specifically, is PING disabled by default on Windows 2008 Enterprise edition?

Any insight on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ICMP, which is what Ping packets are, is not allowed by default by the Server 08 Firewall with Advanced Security.  I am not aware of any difference in the default rules between editions however.  You can either enable ICMP on the local server or through Group Policy on the Firewall with Advanced Security.